# Split a collection to those items that satisfy a predicate, and those that don't

Tags: scala

What's the best way to split a collection into two collections: One that contains all elements satisfying a predicate, and the rest?

```
val nums = List[Integer](1,2,3,4)
val (evens, odds) = nums.split(_ % 2 == 0)
```

Comment: @Antimony - it doesn't compile, `List` doesn't have a `split` method, I just used it as pseudocode. Or ... is there a magical package whose import will give me exactly this?

Comment: no need for magic, scala collections has build-in method `.partition`,  see the link above, which contains exactly your example

Comment: Use [scalex.org](http://scalex.org/) and type in `list[a] => (a => boolean) => (list[a], list[a])`